# (Python/Django/MySQL) Issue with updating form table in HTML page without using php

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I'm a newbie on Python and Django here, I was tasked to create and update a form table in a HTML page using Django and MySQL database without using PHP, I manage to create and display the data but I'm having trouble on the editing/updating part.

How can I do it without using PHP? I'm having trouble understanding on how to use UpdateView. Also I'm trying using 2 ways for user to submit the updated table,

1) by pressing enter 2) by pressing the submit button

Below is my code, I try to use the same code as the one I use to GET the data from input box into the database, but for this it just append another row I last add into the database instead of editing it. I also use dhtmlx to design the table. I've been stuck doing this for days and I really appreciate everyone input in this, Thanks a bunch and apologies for the cluttered codes.

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .form import UserDisplayInfoForm
from .models import UserInfo

def display_view(request, id=None):
    display_table = UserInfo.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = UserDisplayInfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
return render(request, 'myform/display.html',
{"display_table": display_table}, {'form': UserDisplayInfoForm,})
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserInfo
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class UserDisplayInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        template_name = 'myform/display.html'
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "employee_id",
            "gender"
        ]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from myform import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index_view),
    url(r'^display/', views.display_view)
]
```

display.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Lemonsky  v 0.0.1 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/roboto.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.dhtmlx.com/edge/dhtmlx.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdn.dhtmlx.com/edge/dhtmlx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Display Table</h1>
        <h2>Lemonsky  v 0.0.1 </h2>

        <form method="POST" action=""><input type='hidden'/>{% csrf_token %}
            <table class="dhtmlxGrid" id="table_data" name="grid2" gridHeight="auto" style="width:400px" imgpath="myform/static/imgs/" border="1" lightnavigation="true">
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Id</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                    </tr>
                {% for data in display_table %}
                    <tr>
                        <td id="id_first_name" name="first_name"><input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="30" required id="id_first_name" value="{{data.first_name}}"/></td>
                        <td id="id_last_name" name="last_name"><input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="30" required id="id_last_name" value="{{data.last_name}}"/></td>
                        <td id="id_employee_id" name="employee_id"><input type="text" name="employee_id" maxlength="10" required id="id_employee_id" value="{{data.employee_id}}"/></td>
                        <td id="gender" name="gender"><input type="text" name="gender" maxlength="10" required id="id_gender" value="{{data.gender}}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>

            <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("td").keydown(function(event){
                    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;

                        if(keycode == 13){
                            var td_value = $(this).children(':nth-child(1)').val()
                            console.log(td_value);
                            alert(td_value);
                            <!--$.post(URL, data, function(response))-->
                        }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are all the time inserting into the DB new objects.

You should first query if the object exist in the database. Like `Select * from UserInfo where first_name = "test"` but done with Django ORM. Pay attention to do a select with unique id, first_name may not be unique and this is an example.

```
def display_view(request, id=None):
    display_table = UserInfo.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get("first_name", "")
        user = UserInfo.objects.get(first_name = first_name)
        if user:
            form = UserDisplayInfoForm(instance=user)
        else:
            form = UserDisplayInfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
return render(request, 'myform/display.html',
{"display_table": display_table}, {'form': UserDisplayInfoForm,})
```

Comment: Hi @lapinkoira thanks a lot for your reply, I think I'm on the right track already with your help but i received an error :

myform.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one UserInfo -- it returned 4!

how do I solve this issue, do I need to get the other 3 fields, (last_name, employee_id and gender)?

Again I'm very new at this and thanks for your help

Comment: Yes. That makes sense, as I said, you have to find an unique identifer. First name which repeat a lot, for example: John Smith, John Parker, John Garcia.
You are receiving more than one UserInfo.
Try with: first_name = request.POST.get("first_name", "")
last_name = request.POST.get("last_name", "")
        user = UserInfo.objects.get(first_name = first_name, last_name=last_name)
But maybe you can have two John Smith, you need and unique id!

Comment: Thanks for your input again @lapinkoira, the error is gone now and i can see the request.post in my pycharm terminal console but it still doesn't update my database, as you said I do require a unique id or primary key to fix it, I'll look around how to use that but if you have the time, I really appreciate it if you can show me how to do the syntax.

Comment: also sometimes it'll give me "UserInfo matching query does not exist."

Comment: I am sorry but I cant help you with that and I wonder how you dont have the same problem in PHP. You need to model your user instance with an unique id, like NIF or EMAIL so you can query it. But that's very basic database modeling...

Comment: I have a field {id} in my database that generate unique number everytime i post a new data in my database. I'll try to incorporate that in my code later as my primary key. anyway thanks a lot for your help.